# Why is the target/debug/deps directory so big in rust

Tags: macos, rust

Today when I check the rust(1.54) folder, I found the `target/debug/deps` folder using 9.6GB .

```
➜  debug git:(main) ✗ du -sh deps
9.6G    deps
```

why the rust `target/debug/deps` using so much space? is it possible to limit the space using? what should I do to optimize it. There is many files look like this:

```
reddwarf_admin-2f9d6d6d595f65af.2m9e5nlrurh2eiv4.rcgu.o
```

Comment: It's big because it maintains all the incremental build info and never deletes anything. You can delete everything in the `target` directory (either manually or using `cargo clean`) and nothing "bad" will happen, the next compile will just take a while again.

Comment: I'm confused by the presence of the 'incremental directory', and that the size of 'deps' in a clean build with CARGO_INCREMENTAL=false is still very large.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cargo stores there all the results of the compilation (which is already quite big, since Rust's binaries are quite big already), but also much more information (all the incremental build information, as pointed out by @BailpointBen). Their purpose is to not have to recompile everything when making small changes. You can think of them as cache: you can freely delete it, but then the compiler is going to have to make these computations aggain. My advice would be to leave them be while you work on a project, and when you stop `clean` them, so you got ~10G space usage at most due to Rust cache, instead of piling up in each project you have.